# How to stop action execution with another action in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have following actions in a `Test` controller:

```
def run
  while true do
    # code
  end
end

def stop
  # stop the run action
end
```

how can stop action be implemented to halt the run action?

Comment: how do you even come up with such questions?..

Comment: This sounds like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko I'm trying to build web-application like project with play/pause ability.

Comment: @spickermann thanks for the link, I'm trying to implement some application-like behavior in my project

Comment: the web does not work like what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because a client will wait for a response from a server, you can't have a loop in an endpoint that waits for another endpoint to be called.

In this case, a client will visit `/test/run`, but since the server won't return anything until the loop finishes, the client will just keep waiting.

This means (unless you specifically configured your webserver to do so), that another connection can't be made to the server to reach the `test/stop` endpoint.

If you must have a "job" that runs and be cancel-able by an endpoint, turn it into an actual background task.

Comment: Could you, please explain how to do that? Or what are the best practices of solving such issues. Can threading be used in this case, how?

Comment: @AlexanderLomia I think there's probably just a different approach to the problem. What is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to implement some app-like behavior, e.g play/pause ability for different kinds of user-written scripts.

Comment: Not really sure what that means, but from the sounds of it, it's something you'd probably want to be implementing in the front-end. If it's Ruby script, take a look the Opal project https://github.com/opal/opal